# Oxid 7 query parameters in articles are cut off

Tags: php, e-commerce, oxid

I'm using Oxid 7 as a shop system and recently I noticed that my query parameters on the article page are cut off. It doesn't happen on the category page
Example: `myshop.com/prod/testArticle.html?testParam=bla`
So the `?testParam=bla` is cut off. Also on the categories pages it changes to `myshop.com/cat/testCategorie/?testParam=bla`

I tried looking at recent internal code changes but I didn't see anything that could cause the problem. Any idea if that's an issue caused by Oxid or if I have to dig deeper into the current code? I cant show any real code due to an NDA

Comment: If you didn't change anything in the code, the problem may on a different level. Just guessing, the parsing and redirect rules of the provider/apache/nginx changed (due an update or so?) and they forgot that there are also params which should be send. Due NDA nobody can answer this question :)